# Laracast Restler V. 3.0.0rc5 DELETE Method 403 Forbidden Exception

Tags: php, laravel, restler

I'm using Restler V. 3.0.0rc5 to build a PHP Rest API. GET & POST requests are working fine, but for some reason, any attempt to do a DELETE returns a 403 Forbidden error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you don't have the correct `Access Control` headers on your server. Here's some that likely will resolve your issue:

You can put these inside of things like:

- Middleware
- Service Provicers
- Controller `__construct()` methods.

The most common would be something like a `CORS` Middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Then add it to your `routeMiddleware` in your `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Then apply this middleware to routes you wish to expose to the API:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){
    //your API routes
});
```

Then finally, we'll use the following code inside of our `handle` function in our `App\Http\Middleware\Cors` to configure our `headers`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array($request->method, ['post', 'put', 'delete', 'get', 'options'])) {
        return $next($request) 
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept, content-type, 
            x-xsrf-token, x-csrf-token'); // Add any required headers here
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Tweak the header response as you see fit.